# Linux shell commands behave strange with Runtime.exec() (screen command)

Tags: java, linux, runtime

I am sitting here since at least allways on a problem that really beats me down!

I'm writing on a simple and small java program that easily passes any command to a (linux) screen session.

```
Shell command: bash -c "screen -p 0 -S sessionname -X eval 'stuff \"some command\"\015'"
```

When I enter this in the command shell, it all works fine!
But if I let a Java programm do this, nothing happens at all! Not even a message or error or hint! Simply nothing!
I let the program echo the generated screen command and if I take that output and paste it into the shell, it works.

Here is my Java code:

```
    static public void screenCmd() throws IOException
    {
     String command = "bash -c \"screen -p 0 -S screenname -X eval 'stuff \\\"cmd\\\"\\015'\"";

     System.out.println("debug: '" + command + "'"); //output would work
                                                     //when copy and paste it to the shell

     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).getInputStream()
     );

     //for debug output
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
     String line = "";
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
       System.out.println(line);
    }
```

The funniest thing is, that all the other shell commands are working.
I tried Java to exec tail, whomi, cp, ls, ... without any problem. Why not screen?

The Java program is started by the same user who started the screen session.

If somebody has an even small idea please report! I am driving insane here!

p.s.: The screen session also runs a java program! (could that be part of the problem?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is the way the command line is parsed: Java's Runtime.exec doesn't follow the same quoting rules as Bash. You should use the array version of the API instead:

```
String[] command = {"bash", "-c", 
    "screen -p 0 -S screenname -X eval 'stuff \\\"cmd\\\"\\015'"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

You can reduce some of the quoting mess if you exec screen directly without going through bash:

```
String[] command = {"screen", "-p", "0", 
    "-S", "10624.pts-2.koivu", "-X", "eval", "stuff \"cmd\"\\015"};
```

Comment: OK Thanks to anybody who wrote here especially Joni Salonen! ;)

I did it like this now:

public void doCommand(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    String[] cmd = {"screen", "-p", "0", "-S", "screenname", "-X", "eval", "stuff \"" + command + "\"\\015"};
      
    process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
    retVal = process.waitFor();
}

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you try the more modern [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class.

And read these:

1. [Five Common java.lang.Process Pitfalls](http://kylecartmell.com/?p=9)
2. [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)
3. [From Runtime.exec() to ProcessBuilder](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html)

Comment: Nope, that's great.  Thank you, Andrew.

Comment: Hi duffymo, Thanks for the fast advice! But that doesn't help me out! Also with ProcessBuilder, i get the same result! I now made up a bash script with several echos for debugging. All debug messages are put out to the console. But it just skips the screen command!